# Преобразование строки с пробелами в разрядах в число

Tags: javascript

```
parseInt("1 200р"); //возвращает 1
```

Можно как-то сделать, чтобы не учитывался пробел, или нужно предварительно удалять пробелы из строки?

Comment: Насколько мне известно, таки нужно удалить из строки пробелы, а затем использовать `parseInt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все достаточно просто - сначала с помощью регулярного выражения удалим все, кроме цифр и точки, перед этим заменив запятые на точки, если таковые имелись, а потом приведем это к типу int.

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  var str = $("#blah").val();
  alert(parseFloat(str.replace(",",".").replace(/[^0-9.]/gim, "")));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="blah" value="">
<button id="btn">Calc</button>
```

Comment: А если будет 1 200,55р?

Comment: тогда добавить в регулярку про запятые. Написать, или не нужно?

Comment: напишите, пожалуйста

Comment: @Valery, поправил ответ, смотрите выше.